# "Nice summary +1": Wie sagt man das hier?

Tags: word-choice, noun

[Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=summary) zeigt viele Möglichkeiten auf:

> der Abriss
>   die Aufstellung
>   die Auswertung
>   der Auszug   - Text
>   die Inhaltsangabe
>   die Inhaltsübersicht
>   der Kurzbericht
>   die Kurzfassung
>   das Kurzreferat
>   das Resümee
>   das Schlusswort
>   das Summarium [obs.]
>   die Übersicht
>   die Zusammenfassung

Was ist das richtige Wort zum Kommentieren: `"Nice summary! Danke."`?

**Shortly in English and an example**

I want to say in this site `"A nice summary! It is good that someone combines different ideas shortly and succintly so easy to read fast."`.

([more in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6000059#6000059))

Comment: ...es geht auch mit den Wörtern sowie `"Ein guter Überblick der Antworten! +1"` oder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to translate it would be

> Gute Zusammenfassung!

or

> Gute Übersicht!

Comment: `"Guter Überblick!"`, geht das auch?

Comment: @hhh ja, das geht auch.

Comment: *Überblick* passt zwar, ist aber ganz leicht missdeutig: Man kann *einen Überblick verfassen* (d.h. man schreibt eine Zusammenfassung), aber auch *den Überblick haben* (d.h. man durchschaut/begreift/übersieht eine Sache). *Zusammenfassung* oder *Summary* haben nur die erste Bedeutung.